# Collecting retainers

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to create a form that will subtotal a series of charges, but then collect only 50% of that total as a retainer.  and then collect the balance at a later date.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This can be done with a calculation placed into a Price field's Amount field. Without knowing the field name you have I will use the Choice field as my starting field that will be giving me the amount to base my discount calculation on.

The calculation for this will be `=ChoiceField_Amount / 2`